# changed package name, now AndroidManifest.xml doesn't work

Tags: java, android, eclipse

So, I tried to change the package by the following steps I found elsewhere on StackOverflow website:

1. create a new package
2. refractor the package to the new package
3. changing the package line in the form for the `AndroidManifest.xml`
   btw I'm using Eclipse, if that's relevant.

However, I'm getting an error message in the `AndroidManifext.xml` file:

```
Parser exception for /GameProj/AndroidManifest.xml: The prefix "com.p.gameproj.Dataid" for attribute "com.p.gameproj.Dataid:name" associated with an element type "activity" is not bound At line 31.
```

Can someone tell me what the error message means?

Also, here's the `AndroidManifest.xml` file, if it's relevant:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.p.gameproj"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.p.gameproj.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            com.p.gameproj.Creditsname=".Credits"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_credits" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            com.p.gameproj.Dataid:name=".Data"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_data" >
        </activity>
        <activitycom.p.gameproj.CharacterPageandroid:name=".CharacterPage"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_character_page" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            com.p.gameproj.StatPageame=".StatPage"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_stat_page" >
        </activity>
        <activitycom.p.gameproj.MapMain      android:name=".MapMain"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_map_main" >
        </activity>
   com.p.gameproj.ScreenLocvity
            android:name=".ScreenLoc"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_screen_loc"com.p.gameproj.BattleScreen/activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".BattleScreen"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_battle_screen" >
        </com.p.gameproj.InvScreen
        <activity
            android:name=".InvScreen"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_inv_screen"com.p.gameproj.ShopThing  </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ShopThing"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_shop_thing" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like something went wrong during your package name change. Probably a bad find/replace action. There are a several invalid attributes and elements in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file such as the following:

```
<activity
    com.p.gameproj.Dataid:name=".Data"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_data" >
```

Notice the `com.p.gameproj.Dataid:name=".Data"`. It should be `android:name=".Data"`.

Once you fix all these bad values it should work again.

This should be close

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.p.gameproj"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.p.gameproj.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Credits"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_credits" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Data"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_data" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".CharacterPage"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_character_page" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".StatPage"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_stat_page" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MapMain"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_map_main" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ScreenLoc"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_screen_loc">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".BattleScreen"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_battle_screen" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".InvScreen"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_inv_screen">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ShopThing"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_shop_thing" >
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```